# Is there a numerical type (primitive or class) in Java that contains every other numerical type?

Tags: java, math

- Can any number be converted into a Double in Java ?
- If not, is there a Number class that could parse any numerical type
  and that would provide basic mathematical operations ?

I have numbers that can be either int, double, float, long, unsigned float or unsigned long. If I could just call them "Number" it will be easier as all I need from them is to operation like equals, greater than, ...

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html

Comment: Are you looking for a numerical type that provides both arbitrary precision and unlimited size?

Comment: are you trying to write a generic class or something

Comment: @ThomasJager I don't know. I have numbers that can be either int, double, float, long, unsigned float or unsigned long. If I could just call them "Number" it will be easier as all I need from them is to operation like equals, greater than, ...

Comment: I think the `BigDecimal` class may be useful.

Comment: When you have expressions containing two different arithmetic types there is nothing as simple as you seem to be looking for. The easiest Java type that can function as a supertype for at least comparison operations is `BigDecimal`, as noted by @MCEmperor. The BigDecimal class can represent all the values of all the numeric types exactly, and can be easily constructed from them, and implements the `Comparable` interface.

Comment: By the way, Java does not have unsigned types (except for `char`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a numerical type (primitive or class) in Java that contains every other numerical type?

No.

Starting with the primitive types:

- a `byte` doesn't contain all `short` values
- a `short` or `char` doesn't contain all `int` values.
- an `int` doesn't contain all `long` values.
- a `long` doesn't contain all `float` values.
- a `float` doesn't contain all `double` values.

The above are evident from the ranges of the respective types.

- a `double` doesn't contain all `long` values.

This is not quite so obvious.  The range of `double` is larger than the range of `long`, but a `double` has only 53 bits of precision.  If you do the math, this means that there are numbers (integer values) in the range of `long` that *cannot* have an exact representation as `double` values.  `Long.MAX_VALUE` will be one example.

What about `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal`.

- `BigInteger` does not include values in `double` that are not integers.
- `BigDecimal` does not include values that correspond to the ±INF or ±NaN values in `double`

---

> Can any number be converted into a Double in Java?

No, as explained above.  Some `long` values do not have a corresponding `double` value.  There there are `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` values.

> If not, is there a Number class that could parse any numerical type and that would provide basic mathematical operations?

If you are prepared to discount INF and NaN values, and use a large enough `precision` in the `MathContext`, then a `BigDecimal` should good enough ... within the limits of machine memory and of the implementation.

(The current `BigInteger` class has an architectural limit; see [Is there an upper bound to BigInteger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693273/is-there-an-upper-bound-to-biginteger))

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.Number is an abstract super class for many different number types. As such Java is a strongly typed language and expects proper data types at all time. It is true that sometimes it is necessary to convert it to a proper or different data types.

The devil is in the detail. Surely, java.lang.Number is a class that contains every other numerical type.

This seems to do the trick

```
Number number = NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(myString);
```

Courtesy Joakim
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33018384/12011019

Comment: Number doesn't implement Comparable, so I doubt it's what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Hi just quoting a previous thread here as to why Number is comparable. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html     (the above code uses the Object and Text classes in a multi purpose NumberFormat class which can be used to identify locales. As an added bonus we can compare if the number is a decimal or not.:)  )